# Removing OS X on Windows PC to make Windows bootable again

Tags: macos, windows-8, multi-boot, bootloader

I have installed OS X by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD9kfotqbCk), on an Intel Core 2 Duo machine with an ASUS motherboard.

However, I am now unable to boot into my Windows. I'm getting a "boot file missing" error.

Is there any way to remove OS X and get my Windows 8 back?

Comment: You installed OSX on a non-apple machine. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: nothing I mean I just wanted to try the Os X please any help!